# Why won't my Web Api (full framework) Project generated Xml Documentation file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, documentation

I have a WebApi(2 - I think but who knows what that means) project (this is based on a VS 2019 template) that I'm trying to add Xml Documentation to but I can't get the Xml file to generate.

I have this line uncommented in HelpPageConfig.cs

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

I have the appropriate checkbox in my Build properties checked (for debug and release)

[image: Output Options]

I have also added the appropriate comments to all Controllers and Actions but when I build, the Xml file does not get generated and hence I get an exception at runtime

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Users\steve\source\repos\EcmApi\EcmApi\App_Data\XmlDocument.xml'.'
```

I've seen a lot of questions surrounding Publishing (not my problem...yet) and a lot of mentions of something called Swagger (I presume the predecessor to this) but nothing about the file just not being generated at all.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, and I'm not sure how or when, the filename in the HelpPageConfig.cs file and the filename in the build properties got mismatched.  Once I made sure those paths were the same, things worked.